# What is the meaning of the word "have" in this context?

Tags: causative-have

What does the word "**have**" in this context mean? (I know the meanings of this word but this sentence really sound difficult to me how to understand it correctly. I saw a lot definitions for [this word on Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have) so I don't really know to which meaning the writer means).

> What to Do Have your child complete the problems on each page. Point
>   out that they can check their answers by adding the answer to the
>   second number. If that answer matches the ﬁrst number, they know the
>   answer is correct. For example 6 − 2 = 4/4 + 2 = 6.
>
> Some of the pages have a quilt pattern on them. After your child has
>   completed the problems, **have him or her** color the quilt according to the directions at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I've replaced your tag with that for [causative-have]. Click that and you'll find many questions about this.

Answer (score 1):

**To have somebody do something** is a **causative** and it means "to get (or cause) somebody to do something".

It indicates that a person *(which refers to parents in your sentence)* who has the control over someone *(which refers to the child in your sentence)* can cause him/her *(the child)* to do something *(to color the quilt)*.

Answer (score 1):

**To have somebody do something** (here: 'have him or her color the quilt') means *to cause/get somebody to do something* (e. g. to ask, to suggest - in context with a child; to persuade, to force etc. - in another context). The expression uses *bare infinitive* (in the place of '**do**' in the template). Here's a more detailed explanation of grammar behind it:

https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-grammar/to-have-somebody-do-something

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, this is the "causative have". It is more common in US English than British - the entry in the (US) Merriam-Webster has it:

"7 a : to cause or command to do something

—used with the infinitive without to.

have the children stay"